# get caller line number inside parent class method

Tags: python-3.x, inheritance, aws-lambda

I'm trying to get the function caller line number inside parent class. I have defined class like below,

```
from inspect import getframeinfo, stack
class Parent():
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    
    def info(self, message):
        caller = getframeinfo(stack()[1][0])
        print(caller.lineno)
    
class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
    
    def info(self, message):
        super().info(message)
```

After creating object like below it was printing that child class caller line number.

```
child = Child()
child.info("test line")
```

Current Output:

```
15 #super().info(message)
```

Expected Output:

```
18 #child.info("test line")
```

If I create instance for parent class like below it showing correct line number.

```
parent = Parent()
parent.info("test") #output: 18
```

I need to get exact caller line number inside parent class, instead of child class caller. Any help is appreciated.

Generally I'm trying to override aws-lambda-powertools logging library. But it was logging invalid line number because of overriding.

Answer (score 0):

You can patch `inspect.stack` with a wrapper function that deletes the second and third frames from the list returned by the original `inspect.stack`, so that both the call by the child method and the call by the wrapper function are hidden from the parent's `info` method:

```
import inspect
from unittest.mock import patch

class Parent():
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    
    def info(self, message):
        caller = inspect.getframeinfo(inspect.stack()[1][0])
        print(caller.lineno, caller.code_context[0])

def skipping_stack(orig_stack=inspect.stack):
    frames = orig_stack()
    del frames[1:3]
    return frames

class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
    
    def info(self, message):
        with patch('inspect.stack', skipping_stack):
            super().info(message)

child = Child()
child.info("test line")
```

This outputs:

```
26 child.info("test line")
```

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing/LovelyYawningSites

Note that the parent code needs to do:

```
import inspect
```

instead of:

```
from inspect import getframeinfo, stack
```

for the patching to work.